# AND and GROUP BY in Aerospike PHP Client

Tags: php, database, aerospike

I am currently examining aerospike for replacing my company MySQL database. Currently, in MySQL, we have a table that stores the transaction data, the table looks like this :

```
+--------+------------+-----------+------------+-----+--------+
| trx_id | trx_date   | client_id | product_id | qty | total  |
+--------+------------+-----------+------------+-----+--------+
|      1 | 2015-01-01 |         1 |          1 | 100 | 100000 |
|      2 | 2015-01-02 |         2 |          2 | 200 | 200000 |
|      3 | 2015-01-03 |         3 |          3 | 300 | 300000 |
+--------+------------+-----------+------------+-----+--------+
```

For reporting, we usually do something like :

`SELECT MONTH(trx_date), SUM(qty), SUM(total) FROM transaction WHERE client_id = 1 AND product_id = 1 GROUP BY MONTH(trx_date)`

to get the monthly transaction data for a client.

I've read the documentation for the Aerospike PHP client and I don't seem to find anything similar to `AND`, `GROUP BY`, or `MONTH`.

So, in Aerospike PHP client, what is the recommended way to achieve something like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Aerospike is a NoSQL key-value store, and as such you can't expect to use SQL with it. However, using Lua as the User-Defined Function (UDF) language, you can extend the basic functionality.

What you are looking for is an aggregation, applying a [stream UDF](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/developing_stream_udfs.html) to the results of a query.

There is an example of implementing a GROUP BY x HAVING in the PHP client's documentation for the [aggregate()](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/blob/master/doc/aerospike_aggregate.md) method. The thing to remember is that you want the [secondary index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/secondary-index.html) query to eliminate as many records as you can, so that predicate should used for the 'WHERE', and the secondary filtering for the 'AND' should happen inside the stream UDF's filter on the smallest possible data set.

Reading the [UDF Development Guide](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/udf_guide.html) would also help.

Comment: On a separate note, RDBMSs have one way of modeling data so that you can access it with SQL, and key-value stores a different one. You need to figure out whether your application actually needs an RDBMS, because in most cases that isn't so. Web applications tend to denormalize to the point where they are de-facto used as a key-value store, just a really slow, cumbersome one that is bad at scaling.

Comment: I've read the UDF development guide and it seems like I would be able to implement something similar in the UDF. However, my primary concern is performance. I fear that by creating a query that captures as many records as possible to be processed later by the UDF will be slow.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the query's predicate should *eliminate* as many records as possible, which gives the stream UDF a smaller set to operate on. The idea is to shed as much data as you can early in the pipeline. I'll clarify the answer! In your case having the `client_id=1` most likely returns the smallest set, and then filtering on `product=1` in the filter function of the stream UDF. Depending on the number of records returned (on average) you may want to aggregate on the application-side, rather than server-side via UDF. If it's a small number of records the overhead isn't worth it.

Comment: Ahh I see. I was thinking along the same way. Thanks.

Comment: The github link to "aggregate()" is 404'ing.